# Temporary hosting of a web app

Tags: apache-2.2, vps

I need to host a web app for a job application. The app is dependant on an Apache Module, meaning my regular webhost (Dreamhost) cannot support it. My private internet connection also isn't an alternative.

I was thinking about hosting it on a VPS somewhere. Suggestions for a VPS host that maybe has a trial period? Or other solutions?

Comment: I think you need to discuss this on webhosting talk.

Comment: whats the apache module?

Comment: The apache module is the upload progress module, https://github.com/drogus/apache-upload-progress-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth having a look at amazon's free offering for EC2

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

If it is for a job application then being able to throw in the fact you are familiar with popular "cloud" platforms such as AWS never hurts.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - I ended up setting up an EC2 server with Linux. Wasn't too hard to get running. I mainly used http://codelikezell.com/setting-up-rails-mysql-php-apache-and-git-on-ec2/ as a guide. Let's see if the company likes the cloud buzz :-)

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. Useful guide as well

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of VPS providers that can provide daily nodes, however having a virtual private server instead of shared hosting does have a number of benefits (such as an increase in control, reliability and performance) so you may wish to consider taking the small jump from shared hosting to your own private machine.

http://cloudism.net/product/dediserve/

> Dediserve was founded with the
>   passionate belief that Cloud
>   technologies and infrastructure is the
>   future of all hosted services. Cloud
>   IT in particular is the future of all
>   IT services currently living in small
>   business offices, comms rooms,
>   cabinets and colos. Coming online in
>   the beginning of 2009, we have worked
>   to deliver on our mission of low cost,
>   simple to use, transparently priced
>   infrastructure and services to small
>   business, powered by our enterprise
>   cloud platform. Our team is built from
>   evangelists and leaders in the hosting
>   and cloud space with experience in
>   building hosting and cloud platforms
>   to market leading scale.

http://www.vps.net/forum/topic/1196-introducing-standalone-daily-nodes/

> UK2 has been a major player in the web
>   hosting industry since 1998. We have
>   been a profitable company since day
>   one and today we've sold over a
>   million domain names, and we host
>   thousands of websites and dedicated
>   servers for customers in various
>   countries. We can also proudly say
>   that we are one of the biggest and
>   fastest growing web hosting companies
>   in the UK! UK-2 Group is accredited by
>   ICANN (the Internet Corporation for
>   Assigned Names and Numbers) to provide
>   .com, .biz, .info, .net, .org, .jobs,
>   .name and .pro gTLD's to our
>   customers. As a company we have
>   constantly proven ourselves to be a
>   reliable supplier of top quality,
>   professional and low cost affordable
>   services. We believe that customers
>   should always be the core of every
>   business, which is why we are
>   constantly on the look-out ...